# How to do a LEFT JOIN ON OR in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm using Doctrine's querybuilder in Symfony2 to create a query to fetch entities.

I'm trying to get this result in MySQL :

```
SELECT u0_.id AS id0
FROM user u0_ 
LEFT JOIN rva_victims r3_ ON u0_.id = r3_.user_id 
INNER JOIN rva r1_ ON r1_.id = r3_.rva_id or u0_.id = r1_.declarant_id
```

I've tried both ON and WITH conditionType in $qb->join(), but nothing work.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Answer (score 4):

The solution should be pretty straightforward. In your case it should look like this, assuming you're in the repository class:

```
$this
  ->createQueryBuilder('u')
  ->leftJoin(Victims::class, 'v', Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'v.user = u.id')
  ->join(Rva::class, 'r', Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.id = v.rva OR u.id = r.declarant');
```

This should work fine, I am just assuming the class names right now. Please also take in account that all the conditions are done on class attribute names (DQL), not column names.

Comment: My problem is, Victims and Rva are in the same entity.

In fact, i have my Rva entity, which contains a victims attribute Rva@ManyToMany("User") and a declarant attribute Rva@ManyToOne("User").

I need to get all victims and declarant in the same request.

My problem in your join, is the WITH, because I get the result : INNER JOIN rva r4_ ON u0_.id = r4_.declarant_id AND (r4_.declarant_id IN (?) OR u0_.id = r4_.declarant_id)

Comment: Can you please update the question with the involved model definitions? It would be more clear what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a query builder in entity repository

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
     ->leftJoin('yourbundle:Entityname', 'ye', 'WITH', 'u0_.id = r3_.user_id')
     ->innerJoin('yourbuncle:entityname', 'yen', 'WITH', 'r1_.id = r3_.rva_id', 'OR', 'u0_.id = r1_.declarant_id');
```

Comment: I got `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 155 near 'OR WITH rvaD.declarant': Error: 'OR' does not point to a Class.`

Comment: Have you tried to enter like this  'r1_.id = r3_.rva_id OR u0_.id = r1_.declarant_id'... also did you get the rows that you wanted with that sql query on mysql client